# RavenDB Restore Stuck

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio, ravendb-http

We are trying to restore Ravendb from the backup file. We are using Raven studio. The restore process copied index files from the backup to the new location but it's stuck at the below step:

```
Esent Restore: Restore Begin 
Esent Restore: 18 1001
```

I couldn't see any other logs or exceptions.

The backup size is around 123 GB.

How do I fix this stuck process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of investigation, I found the issue.

Seems the IIS application pool was configured to recycle itself every 20 min. So, after 20 mins, RavenDB was used to kill the restore process.

I found the issue by monitoring the Resouce Monitor -> CPU -> Process Manager tab. You should able to see the Raven process doing loads of write operations during restore and should able to monitor when service gets stopped.

[image]